# Proof involving Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Suppose $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{m_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$ where each $m_i$ is a positive integer (not necessarily prime). Let $p$ be a prime, and  let $s$ be the number of $m_i$'s divisible by $p$. Show that $G${$p$} $\simeq \mathbb{Z}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is crossed with itself $s$ times and $G${$p$}={$a \in G | pa = 0_G$}.

I have no idea why this would be the case any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess $\times$ means that $G$ is also abelian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that if $G_1,\dots,G_t$ are finite abelian groups, then 
$$(G_1\times\dots\times G_t)[p]\simeq G_1[p]\times\dots\times G_t[p]$$
since $x=(x_1,\dots,x_t)$ satisfies $px=0$ if and only if $px_i=0$ for each $i$.

So it's enough to determine $G[p]$ when $G=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. If $m$ is prime to $p$ then $p$ is invertible mod $m$, hence $pG=G$, so $G[p]=0$.

And if $p|m$ and $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $px\equiv 0$ (mod $m$) if and only if $\frac{m}{p}$ divides $x$. Therefore
$$ G[p]=\frac{m}{p}\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$
when $p|m$. Combining the above results shows that
$$ G[p]\simeq \Big(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\Big)^s $$
if exactly $s$ of the $m_i$ are divisible by $p$.